# Prove that the set $S\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ is countable.

Tags: real-analysis

Given a set $S\subseteq \mathbb{ R}$ with the property that for every $ x\in S$ there is an open interval $I$ containing $x$
such that $I\cap S$ is countable. Prove that S is countable.

I am trying to write $S$ as a countable union of countable sets by using the given property of intersection, but not getting the suitable idea. Please suggest me. Thanks a lot.

Comment: have you tried expressing $\mathbb{R}$ as a countable union of closed intervals e.g. $[n,n+1]$ then using a compacness argument for each interval?

Comment: **Hint:** we can use a countable *topological basis* for $\Bbb R$ that consists of open intervals.

Comment: no i did't try like this...but now i am think according to you...

Comment: Hint: $\mathbb{R}$ is *second-countable* (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second-countable_space), thus you can extend the collection of $I_x$'s to a cover of $\mathbb{R}$ by open sets, and then invoke second-countability to reduce that cover to a countable cover. This cover still satisfies (by necessity) that $\forall x$ there is an $I$ such that $x\in I$, and since the intersections with the original $I$'s were countable, so to must the intersections with the reduced cover. Therefore, $S$ is countable.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom i am trying without using general toplogical ideas...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $S$ be a set so that for every $x\in S$ there is an open interval $U$ containing $x$ so that $U\cap S$ s countable.

It follows that  for every $x\in S$ we can select an open interval $U_x=(a,b)$ so that $x\in U_x$, $U_x\cap S$ is countable and $a$ and $b$ are rational.

Cleary $S\subseteq\bigcup\limits_{x\in S} U_x$, it follows that   $S=S\cap(\bigcup\limits_{x\in S} U_x)=\bigcup\limits_{x\in S}(S\cap U_x)$.

This last union is equal to a countable union of countable sets, because the number of open intervals with rational endpoints is countable.

Comment: yes i was searching this type of idea....

Comment: @CarryonSmiling  But last union is over elements of $S$, then how is it countable union? intervals may not be distinct..

Comment: $U_x$ is always an interval with rational endpoints, there is only a countable number of intervals of this form.

Comment: every thing is ok ...my confusion is just about last union as its also depends with elements of $S.$

Comment: the set $U_x$ such that $x\in S$ is countable, this clearly implies the set $S\cap U_x$ such that $x\in S$ is countable.

Comment: Every real number can be put in an interval of rational endpoint.. then isn't there as much intervals with rational endpoints as there are real numbers?

Comment: Yes the same thing i am saying that Last union only depends on $x$ such that $x\in S.$

Comment: @madmatician clearly not, everyone knows $\mathbb Q \times \mathbb Q$ is countable. By your logic $\mathbb N$ is uncountable, since every real can be put in an interval of the form $[n,n+1]$

Comment: Each term of last union is countable but my confusion is that last union itself is not countable...i think so...

Comment: @neelkanth ok, let's try again. First things first, do you agree that the set $\{U_x| x\in S\}$ is countable ?

Comment: Its only thing that is not clear...

Comment: How is it countable..its not the collection of intervals with rational end points..

Comment: ok, the set $\{U_x|x\in S\}$ is a subset of the set $\{(a,b) | a,b\in \mathbb Q\}$, and the second set is countable.

Comment: Yes its subset...

Comment: You are aware that if a set is countable all of its subsets are also countable right?

Comment: Yes i know that subset of a countable set is countable...

Comment: Ok, so then $\{U_x|x\in S \}$ is countable, as it is a subset of the countable se $\{(a,b)|a,b\in \mathbb Q\}$

Comment: ok Done....thanks a lot ...

Comment: sure, no problem.

Comment: i got it ...thanks for your precise time.....

Answer (score 1):

Write $\mathbb{R}=\bigcup\limits_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\,[-n,+n]$ and $S_n:=[-n,+n]\cap S$ for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$.  Then, consider the open cover of $[-n,+n]$ consisting of $[-n,+n]\setminus \bar{S}_n$, where $\bar{S}_n$ is the topological closure of $S_n$, and all open intervals $I$ that contain $x\in S_n$ with $I\cap S$ being countable.

Comment: Let $s : \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{Q}$ be an enumeration of $\mathbb{Q}$. Let $I_n$ denote an interval such that $s(n) \in I_n$ where $I_n \cap S$ is countable. Then $\mathbb{R} = \cup_{n = 1}^{\infty} I_n$, so $S = \cup_{n = 1}^{\infty} (I_n \cap S)$, a countable union of countable sets.